# Building binutils: having problems with sed

Tags: sed, configure, binutils

I was trying to build binutils as I was building the mingw-w64 toolchain, when I run into this weird problem involving `sed` when configuring ([configure output](https://pastebin.com/a9AYum53)). `sed --version` returns version 4.5. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a `mingw64` version of `sed` and it was conflicting with `msys2` `sed`. I deleted that and now it works fine